# how to get app name and app version in android using gcm 3.0 API

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am referring this official video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJatfdattno

Here that talk about we can get app version and app name (package name) using GCM API. I searched on google and found nothing.

Did anyone have any idea on what API to use to get APP version and app name?

Comment: Sorry it is not clear for me. Are you interested in your own application's version and app name?

Comment: @jbarat.. yes. I am looking for GCM API to get my own application's version and app name.

Comment: You can use [Instance ID](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/). It provides a simple API to generate security tokens that authorize third parties to access your app's server side managed resources. You need to pass Instance ID tokens to your server and use the Instance ID service to verify the app package name. Here's how to implement it in [Android](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation). You can see the example [here](https://github.com/srujanmaddula/GCM_with_instanceID).